# Nested Functions lead to Segmentation fault in C on kernel versions > 5.7

Tags: c, operating-system

First SO question, so here it goes.

I'm not asking for someone to review the code, i want to get to the bottom of this.
It would be helpful if someone knew what change in the kernel could be responsible for the following.

In the University we were tasked to implement extended functionality in a modeled Operating System written in C (written by my professor), that models each core with a pthread.

Project [github](https://github.com/the-rectifier/tinyos3) forked  by me.

We had to implement the necessary functionality by implementing the required syscalls. (multithreading, sockets, pipes, mlfq, etc).

After implementing each functionality we had to confirm that it was working using the [validate_api](https://github.com/the-rectifier/tinyos3/blob/master/validate_api.c) program.

**Problem time:**

The validate_api.c contains a lot of tests to check the functionality of the OS.

**BOOT_TEST:** bare-boots the machine and tests something.

A simple test for creating a new thread inside a process:

```
BOOT_TEST(test_create_join_thread,
    "Test that a process thread can be created and joined. Also, that "
    "the argument of the thread is passed correctly."
    )
{
    int flag = 0;

    int task(int argl, void* args) {
        ASSERT(args == &flag);
        *(int*)args = 1;
        return 2;
    }

    Tid_t t = CreateThread(task, sizeof(flag), &flag);

    /* Success in creating thread */
    ASSERT(t!=NOTHREAD);
    int exitval;
    
    /* Join should succeed */
    ASSERT(ThreadJoin(t, &exitval)==0);

    /* Exit status should be correct */
    ASSERT(exitval==2);

    /* Shared variable should be updates */
    ASSERT(flag==1);

    /* A second Join should fail! */
    ASSERT(ThreadJoin(t, NULL)==-1);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see there is a nested function called **task**() which is the starting point of the thread that is going to be created using the **createThread**() syscall we implemented.

**The problem is** that, although the thread is created correctly, when scheduled to run, the program exits with segmentation fault and cannot access the memory of the task function, gdb doesn't even recognize it as a variable (in the [thread struct field](https://github.com/the-rectifier/tinyos3/blob/master/kernel_threads.h) pointing to it). **The weird thing is that this happens ONLY when using a kernel version newer than 5.7**. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/vsamtuc/tinyos3/issues/6) in the original project's repo.

Running the actual OS and its programs it's fine with no issues whatsoever, only validate_api fails due to that nested function. If i move the task function into global scope then the test finishes successfully. Same goes for every other test that has a nested function inside.

Note: The project is finished (1 month now), i downgraded to 5.4 just to test my implementation.

Note2: I dont need help with the implementation of any functionality (the project is finished any way), i just want to figure out why it doesn't work on kernels > 5.7

Note3: I'm here because my prof. doesn't respond to my repeated emails regarding the issue

I tried compiling using -fno-stack-protector and with -z execstack with no luck. Also simple nested functions like:

```
int main(){
    int foo(){
        puts("Hello there");
    }
    foo();
}
```

work with any kernel

Machine Details:

Arch Linux - 5.10 / 5.4 LTS

GCC 10.2

Thank you

UPDATE:
The test joins the thread, so it never goes out of scope.

Comment: @FredLarson i tried compiling using gnu11 as well, no luck. About the boot test, do you mean the MACRO that expands the BOOT_TEST is written in c++?

Comment: Oh, `BOOT_TEST` -- I read that as `BOOST_TEST` Sorry, that's different. I have no idea what `BOOT_TEST` is.

Comment: it's a macro that calls the bios to boot up the OS. In any case since the C standard does not support local functions why does it work on 5.4 kernel (-std=c11 in makefile)?

Comment: You're likely using a compiler that supports local functions as an extension to the language (like gcc). If the compiler didn't support local functions this wouldn't compile successfully.

Comment: do you have any idea what might have changed between 5.7 and 5.8 to cause such problems (invalid memory) since the extensions are working fine?

Comment: I would add this as a comment, but my account is too new: Perhaps the issue is related to this [vulnerability](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2018/q4/82) in GCC? Nested functions stack space were marked as executable for certain versions, and this may have changed across older versions (the thread doesn't document which, if any, previous versions are affected)

Comment: *Tid_t t = CreateThread(task, sizeof(flag), &flag);*  creates a thread where `flag` **is not guaranteed to exist when the thread actually runs**.

Comment: using both kernel versions i compiled using GCC 10.2

Comment: @AndrewHenle how is that? the flag in declared before the thread is being created, also moving just the task() to global scope fixes the test

Comment: Well, I would expect 'flag' to be illegal for read/write because it's frame offset is invalid on the stack of the new thread.

Comment: I am not convinced that the different calling convention and stack frame/layout required for nested functions is compatible with thread creation.  I mean, you are breaking the isolation provided by nested functions by calling one from outside the parent using a different stack:)

Comment: Also, does GCC still use trampolines to access nested functions, 'cos the tramp code will be missing on the stack of the new thread.

Comment: breaking isolation makes sense to me.
From my research a couple of months ago, i stumbled across a kernel commit for 5.8 regarding the trampoline, now miraculously i can't find it...
Using the flag -Wtrampoline in GCC confirms that it still uses trampolines.